# doubled savings with core data swift 4

Tags: core-data, swift4

developing a little app for my comic collection encountered this issue:

in my second "add comic" VC I have a button and the func below, but I save TWICE entities in manged context (ate least, I think this is the issue)

for example if I have 2 comics yet shown in main VC tableview, go to "add comic VC" and save a third one, going back to main VC I'll print 3 objects with title, number etc but also print 2 new objects with no data as I had saved twice a manger context a "right one" and another one with same number of object but empty. If I keep adding a 4th comic, I'll get 6 complete comic + the 4th and more 6 "blank itmes" with default values "no title"

```
let kComicEntityName = "Comic"





func addingSingleComic(gotTitle: String, gotIssue: Int16, gotInCollection: Bool ) {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: kComicEntityName, in: managedContext)!

        let comicToAdd = Comic(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        comicToAdd.comicTitle = gotTitle
        comicToAdd.issueNumber = gotIssue
        comicToAdd.inCollection = gotInCollection

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        print("new single comic crated: title: \(comicToAdd.comicTitle ?? "!! not title !!"), n. \(comicToAdd.issueNumber), owned?: \(comicToAdd.inCollection)")

    }
```

in the main VC I use this to check items in core data

```
 func asyncPrintEntities() {

        self.asyncComicEntityArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)


        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let comicFetch : NSFetchRequest<Comic> = Comic.fetchRequest()

        asyncFetchRequest = NSAsynchronousFetchRequest<Comic>(fetchRequest: comicFetch) {
            [unowned self] (result: NSAsynchronousFetchResult) in
            guard let AllComicEntityResult = result.finalResult else {
                return
            }

            self.asyncComicEntityArray = AllComicEntityResult


            //************************************

            do {
                self.asyncComicEntityArray = try managedContext.fetch(comicFetch)
                if self.asyncComicEntityArray.count > 0 {
                    print("Ok! model is not empty!")
                } else {
                    print("No entites availabe")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Fetch error: \(error) description: \(error.userInfo)")
            }


            guard self.asyncComicEntityArray != nil else {return}
            for comicFoundInArray in self.asyncComicEntityArray {
                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: self.kComicEntityName, in: managedContext)!
                var comicTouse = Comic(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
                //            var comicTouse = Comic() //to be deleted since this kind of init is not allowed, better above insertInto
                comicTouse = comicFoundInArray as! Comic
                print("comic title: \(comicTouse.comicTitle ?? "error title"), is it in collection? : \(comicTouse.inCollection)")
            }

            self.MyTableView.reloadData()

            //************************************
        }
        // MARK: - async fetch request 3
        do {
            try managedContext.execute(asyncFetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }


        //end of function
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing in that code that would cause duplication. Does the `print` appear too many times?

Comment: No, I think issue is somewhere in the fact that this code is in the second VC from the main, where a tebleview shows async fetch results, and both are embedded in navigation controller. somehow Im saving data twice maybe getting data from a "second managed context"if possible. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `addingSingleComic` you create a new `Comic` here:

```
let comicToAdd = Comic(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
```

Then you assign values to the object's properties.

Separately, in `asyncPrintEntities`, you also create new `Comic` objects here:

```
var comicTouse = Comic(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
```

This time you **do not** assign values to the object's properties. They will have no title, etc, because you created them but never assigned a title. This line executes once for every object in `asyncComicEntityArray`, so if the array has two objects, you create two new objects that contain no data. You don't use `comicToUse` anywhere except in the one `print`, but it still exists in the managed object context and will still get saved the next time you save changes.

This is why you're getting extra entries-- because you're creating them in this line of code. It's not clear why you're creating them here. You just executed a fetch request, and then you immediately create a bunch of no-data entries which you don't use. It looks like that entire `for` loop could just be deleted, because the only thing it does is create these extra entries.

Comment: I see, but how could then "grab" data and use them in the Tableview? I commented the line where i created an instance since it is not allowed.

Comment: The fetch request gives you objects that can be displayed in a table. You don’t need to do anything else because you already have the result you want. If you’re going to use a table view you might find it simpler to use `NSFetchedResultsController`.